# Valve Basestations 2.0 not properly working with SteamVR

Tags: ubuntu, steam-vr, vive

I am trying to setup SteamVR to work on Ubuntu 16.04 with two Valve Basestations 2.0 and a HTC Vive tracker.

What I did so far is to put the two basestations 5 meters apart and looking at each other. Then, if I put the HTC Vive tracker in the middle and run SteamVR, this is what I get.

[image]

[image]

That is, it looks like only one basestation is properly working. In fact, the room overview shows the same situation.

[image]

We configured the [null](https://sites.google.com/view/brown-vr-sw-review-2018/vr-hardware/hardware-emulators/null-driver-tutorial) driver to disable the headset. Can this be the cause?

The headset is disabled at startup.

```
   "LastKnown" : {
      "HMDModel" : "Null Model Number"
   },
   "direct_mode" : {
      "enable" : false
   },
   "driver_null" : {
      "displayFrequency" : 30,
      "enable" : true,
      "id" : "Null Driver",
      "renderHeight" : 300,
      "renderWidth" : 640,
      "secondsFromVsyncToPhotons" : 0.10000000149011612,
      "serialNumber" : "Null 4711",
      "windowHeight" : 300,
      "windowWidth" : 640,
      "windowX" : 100,
      "windowY" : 100
   },
```

How can I fix this issue and have both basestations to work?

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to one of two possibilites:

1. The tracker is too far from the headset
2. There is no direct sight line between the headset and the tracker

Make sure it's close with nothing blocking the sensor.